# HTML CSS responsive Card

Tags: html, css

I am making a card with header in HTML and CSS. Appreciate your advice on how can I make it responsive. I tried so many ways but I can't seem to have it worked. Do I need to change some code so that the webpage will be responsive?

```css
.section1{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.section2{
  width:95%;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #182035;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.section3{
  width:95%;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #182035;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 30rem;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
  text-align: center;

}

h3{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  color:#ecb445;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-family: Coldiac;
}

.container{
  background-color:#ecb445;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}



/*CARD*/
.card {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:0.2rem solid #182035;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all ease 0.4s
}

.card img {
    width:22rem;
    height:auto;
    margin-top: -2.5rem;
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
}

.card:hover img {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.card .content {
    width: 20.5rem;
    height:17rem;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.09)
}

.card .content .category {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.card .content .price {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
}

.card .content p {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px
}

.card:hover .content {
    bottom: 0%
}

.buttons button {
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all ease 0.3s
}

.content {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.category{
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

#btn2{
  background-color:transparent;
  border-color: #df4648;
  color:#df4648;
}

#btn2:hover{
  background-color:#df4648;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="section2">
      <h3> Paper Stock </h3>
      <div class="container mt-4 mb-3">
        <div class="row g-2">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/glossy.jpeg" class="img-fluid" width="200" /> </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Glossy
                    Paper</span> </div>
                <p> <b> Description: </b>a semi-gloss finish, unlike glossy paper. Matte paper also produces a
                  high-quality print albeit loses the vibrant effect that Gloss paper has.
                  <br><br> <b> Size: </b> 8.5x11/A4 <br> <b> Black & White: </b> ₱1.50/page <br> <b> Slightly Colored:
                  </b> ₱5.00/ page <br> <b> Full Colored: </b> ₱8.00/ page
                </p>
                <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                    id="btn2">Print Now </button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/matte.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="200" /> </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Matte
                    Paper</span></div>
                <p> <b> Description: </b>a smooth-coated paper designed to present an ultra-smooth and shiny appearance
                  <br><br>
                  <b> Size: </b> 8.5x11/A4 <br> <b> Black & White: </b> ₱1.50/page <br> <b> Slightly Colored: </b>
                  ₱5.00/ page <br> <b> Full Colored: </b> ₱8.00/ page
                </p>
                <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                    id="btn2">Print Now </button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/textured.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="200" /> </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Textured
                    Paper</span></div>
                <p> <b> Description: </b>has four different kinds; smooth, embossed, uncoated, and coated. Each of the
                  four kinds has their own unique appearance and texture.<br><br>
                  <b> Size: </b> 8.5x11/A4 <br> <b> Black & White: </b> ₱1.50/page <br> <b> Slightly Colored: </b>
                  ₱5.00/ page <br> <b> Full Colored: </b> ₱8.00/ page
                </p>
                <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                    id="btn2">Print Now</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="section3">
    <h3>Ink</h3>
      <div class="container mt-4 mb-3">
        <div class="row g-2">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/hpink.jpg" class="img-fluid" width="200"/> </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Hewlett Packard</span> </div>
                        <p> <b> Description: </b>Hewlett Packard, or HP, uses cartridges which are recycled. HP cartridges also has a reputation for being “ink-spill-free.” <br><br> <b> HP GT52 </b> <br> <b> Product Type: </b> Ink Cartridge <br> <b> Yield: </b> Standard-Yield <br> <b> Price: </b> ₱360.00 </p>
                       <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1" id="btn2">Buy Now </button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/epsonink.png" class="img-fluid" width="200" /> </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Epson</span></div>
                        <p> <b> Description: </b>Although inks manufactured by Epson costs a lot, they provide quality, true-to-life, and sharp prints for businesses. <br><br>
                        <b> Epson 664 </b> <br> <b> Product Type: </b> Ink Cartridge <br> <b> Yield: </b> Standard-Yield <br> <b> Price: </b> ₱299.00</p>
                        <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1" id="btn2">Buy Now</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="text-center"> <img src="images/canonink.png" class="img-fluid" width="200" /> </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> <span class="category">Canon</span></div>
                        <p> <b> Description: </b>Canon inks has a history for having inks that blend well with other colors, they are sold at a fair price <br><br>
                        <b> Canon GT-790</b> <br> <b>Product Type: </b>Ink Cartridge<br> <b> Yield: </b> Standard-Yield <br> <b> Price: </b> ₱499.000 </p>
                        <div class="buttons d-flex justify-content-center"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1" id="btn2">Buy Now</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Based on many of the classes I see in your HTML is looks like you're using Bootstrap, which is responsive by default

Comment: [  https://new-programmer-tech.github.io/HTML-CSS-CARDS/activist  ] check out this website you will get to know. and also, go throw its source code. source code:- [ 
  https://github.com/new-programmer-tech/HTML-CSS-CARDS  ]

Answer (score 0):

Take help from this code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .box {
        width: 300px;
        height: 250px;
        color: blue;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        margin:3rem 3rem;
    }

    #box1 {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    #box2 {
        background-color: rgb(229, 255, 0);
    }

    #box3 {
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 68);
    }

    #box4 {
        background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
    }

    #box5 {
        background-color: rgb(35, 57, 126);
    }

    #box6 {
        background-color: rgb(25, 155, 43);
    }



    .container{
        border:4px solid black;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding:10px 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box6"></div>
    </div>

    <body>

</html>
```